# Dot plot with error bars in ggplot changes order of presentation of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

Oh Wise Men & Women of the R!

I created a dot plot with error bars in ggplot2. I got it to work as intended, for the most part. However, it seems to "randomly" (as far as I could tell) invert the order in which it presents the data for the two types of material I analyzed.

This is my code:

```
data<-data.frame("Mat_art"=c("Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners"), "CompIDinv"=c(17, 17, 16, 16, 15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 10), "Comp"=c("Cheese", "Cheese", "Mayo", "Mayo", "Ketchup", "Ketchup", "Glue", "Glue", "Tofu", "Tofu", "Ranch", "Ranch", "Marmite", "Marmite", "Butter", "Butter"), "Prom"=c(1.15968339356004, 1.09598175499146, 0.606871622602421, 0, 0.477223208284233, 0, 1.52931048485049, 0.499586619837113, 1.33614656021619, 1.95359709169813, 1.22093637869439, 2.34963432630937, 1.35262980291428, 1.69298650050846, 1.35086700266383, 1.24031665670217), "infCI95"=c(0.775987209086803, 0.727123902187271, 0.388630354128953, 0, 0.406186682979503, 0, 1.1431692694034, 0.318904748424858, 1.19987305571909, 1.03758502964521, 1.11361766267652, 2.09487026135963, 1.24530044274135, 0.543063809010205, 0.993468721657989, 0.695707000558221), "supCI95"=c(1.54337957803327, 1.46483960779564, 0.825112891075889, 0, 0.548259733588963, 0, 1.91545170029758, 0.680268491249369, 1.47242006471328, 2.86960915375105, 1.32825509471225, 2.60439839125911, 1.4599591630872, 2.84290919200671, 1.70826528366967, 1.78492631284613), "Color"=c("4", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), "Etiqueta"=c("Immobilization", "Conservation", "Degradation", "Degradation", "Degradation", "Degradation", "Immobilization", "Degradation", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization"))

data$Comp<-as.factor(data$Comp)
data$Mat_art<-as.factor(data$Mat_art)
data$Etiqueta<-as.factor(data$Etiqueta)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = reorder(Comp,CompIDinv), y = Prom, ymin = infCI95, ymax = supCI95, colour = reorder(Etiqueta, Color), shape=Mat_art)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 2)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), width = 0.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#D55E00")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, linetype="dashed", color = "black", size=1) +
  labs(x = "Dip", y = "Yummyness", colour = "Behavior", shape = "Material") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

And this is the plot I'm getting out of it:

[Dotplot with orders randomly changing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywGpb.png)

As you can see, for "Cheese", Apples comes first, but then it switches to Naners first up to "Glue" and then again till the end. My intention is for Apples to come first **always** (no offense meant to those that like naners better :D). This happens a couple more times in the complete data set, of which these are actual values. Of course it's not about dipping your naners in glue, don't worry.

Anyway, I would be super grateful if you'd be willing to help me out on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code, mainly reordered factors first instead of within `ggplot`:

```
data$Comp<-as.factor(data$Comp)
data$Mat_art<-factor(data$Mat_art, levels = c("Naners", "Apples"))
data$Etiqueta<-factor(data$Etiqueta, levels = c("Degradation", "Conservation", "Immobilization"))

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = reorder(Comp,CompIDinv), y = Prom, ymin = infCI95, ymax = supCI95, 
                        colour = Etiqueta, shape=Mat_art
                       )) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 2)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), width = 0.5) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#D55E00")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, linetype="dashed", color = "black", size=1) +
  labs(x = "Dip", y = "Yummyness", colour = "Behavior", shape = "Material") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply!

I see indeed you managed to make it work. I have a small problem, though. I actually load all my data from an xlsx file using read.xlsx. I tried your approach (I think), making the material I want to appear on top also appear first in the corresponding column. But it didn't work for me, I still get the same switching :S. What would I have to do in this case? The xlsx file has the exact same structure, once loaded in R, as my original data set before being edited.

Comment: It is difficult to answer here. If you post a separate post with a reproducible example, I would be happy to give a try.

Comment: Greetings again and thank you! I posted a new question detailing my actual process, I would be very grateful if you could take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68042944/16249358