# Dot plot in ggplot from xlsx file changes order of presentation of data

Tags: r, ggplot2

This relates to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68013895/dot-plot-with-error-bars-in-ggplot-changes-order-of-presentation-of-data/68014577?noredirect=1#comment120238089_68014577).

I have an xlsx file with this structure and data:[image]

It can be generated in R with the following code:

```
data<-data.frame("Mat_art"=c("Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners", "Apples", "Naners"), "CompIDinv"=c(17, 17, 16, 16, 15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11, 10, 10), "Comp"=c("Cheese", "Cheese", "Mayo", "Mayo", "Ketchup", "Ketchup", "Glue", "Glue", "Tofu", "Tofu", "Ranch", "Ranch", "Marmite", "Marmite", "Butter", "Butter"), "Prom"=c(1.15968339356004, 1.09598175499146, 0.606871622602421, 0, 0.477223208284233, 0, 1.52931048485049, 0.499586619837113, 1.33614656021619, 1.95359709169813, 1.22093637869439, 2.34963432630937, 1.35262980291428, 1.69298650050846, 1.35086700266383, 1.24031665670217), "infCI95"=c(0.775987209086803, 0.727123902187271, 0.388630354128953, 0, 0.406186682979503, 0, 1.1431692694034, 0.318904748424858, 1.19987305571909, 1.03758502964521, 1.11361766267652, 2.09487026135963, 1.24530044274135, 0.543063809010205, 0.993468721657989, 0.695707000558221), "supCI95"=c(1.54337957803327, 1.46483960779564, 0.825112891075889, 0, 0.548259733588963, 0, 1.91545170029758, 0.680268491249369, 1.47242006471328, 2.86960915375105, 1.32825509471225, 2.60439839125911, 1.4599591630872, 2.84290919200671, 1.70826528366967, 1.78492631284613), "Color"=c("4", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "2", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), "Etiqueta"=c("Immobilization", "Conservation", "Degradation", "Degradation", "Degradation", "Degradation", "Immobilization", "Degradation", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization", "Immobilization"))
```

But I ***always*** load it from file with read.xlsx. With this file, I produce the following plot:
[image]

The problem with this plot is that it inverts, in a seemingly random manner, the appearance of the dots for Apples and Naners (an their corresponding bars). I would like for Apples to ALWAYS come on top and Naners bellow. Thanks to @Zhiqiang Wang I now realize I could do it by inverting the order of the factors, if I were to generate the dataframe in R. But I never do this, I always import it from the Excel file, and would like to know how to force the order to produce the correct plot with this approach. The actual code I use is the following:

```
library(xlsx)
library(ggplot2)

data=read.xlsx("FILE_NAME.xlsx", "SHEET_NAME")

data$Comp<-as.factor(data$Comp)
data$Mat<-as.factor(data$Mat)
data$Mat_art<-as.factor(data$Mat_art)
data$Etiqueta<-as.factor(data$Etiqueta)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = reorder(Comp,CompIDinv), y = Prom, ymin = infCI95, ymax = supCI95, colour = reorder(Etiqueta, Color), shape=Mat_art)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 15)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), size = 3.5) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), width = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, linetype="dashed", color = "black", size=1) +
  labs(x = "Dip", y = "Yummyness", colour = "Behavior", shape = "Material") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black") , axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=20), legend.title=element_text(size=20), legend.text=element_text(size=15))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the same problem as your previous post, dealing with factor levels. I can only answer your question based on the reproducible examples provided by you.

It is more about data than `ggplot`. If you want to reorder a factor variable, try to reorder it before `ggplot`, unless there are some reasons not to do so. This way, you can check if reorder actually works. To fix your problem:

1. In your code: `reorder(Etiqueta, Color)` does not work and gives some warning messages. The graph is not ordered accordingly. Because your `Color` variable is character not numeric as required by the function `reorder`. You need to convert it to numeric.
2. Add `m_levels <- sort(unique(data$Mat_art), decreasing = TRUE)`, and use `m_levels` to reorder `Mat_art`. I do not know why this is needed but it works.

```
data$Comp<-as.factor(data$Comp)
data$Mat<-as.factor(data$Mat)
data$Etiqueta<-as.factor(data$Etiqueta)

#added or modified 
data$Color = as.numeric(data$Color)
m_levels <- sort(unique(data$Mat_art), decreasing = TRUE) 
data$Mat_art<-factor(data$Mat_art, levels = m_levels)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = reorder(Comp,CompIDinv), 
                          y = Prom, ymin = infCI95, 
                          ymax = supCI95, 
                          colour = reorder(Etiqueta, Color), 
                          shape=Mat_art)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 15)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), size = 3.5) +
  geom_errorbar(position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), width = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#0072B2", "#009E73", "#F0E442", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, linetype="dashed", color = "black", size=1) +
  labs(x = "Dip", y = "Yummyness", colour = "Behavior", shape = "Material") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black") , axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=20), legend.title=element_text(size=20), legend.text=element_text(size=15))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello again, and thank you for your help once more. I was able to implement your solution upon my larger data set with almost complete success, there is always at least one set that flips and is left with the materials inverted, try as I might. Curiously, what I wasn't able to do, and I see you were not either, is to present the legend's order in the same way the materials are ordered in the plot, if I invert the legends order, then all the data gets flipped in the plot, and not even in a consistent manner. I think I'll leave it as is and hope for the best! Thanks again!

Comment: I don’t have my computer with me but I think that’s possible. I will have a look later

Comment: Try add  `+  guides(shape = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))` . You may need to try different combinations of `guides`, and may even need to reorder of your factor variables.

Comment: YES! That totally fixed it. The only mystery left is a single instance were they always appear inverted, I think it was because of the values being plotted (< 0 vs 0), in my case I could put a 0 where it was < 0, I think the color coding will be enough. Thank you :D.